# Prolog showing results on the interpretator

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I have this prolog predicate that computes the number of primes depending on the input count.

However on the interpretator, it only shows the first 9 primes even though I input my required prime count as 10.

the result looks like this as below

```
  L = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23|...]
```

However, when I trace through using the graphical debugger, the correct results are actually churned out.

So I am wondering what does the | ... means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpreter truncates answers that are "too long".

Add this at the top:

```
set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options, [quoted(true)])
```

See example of this:
http://garysieling.com/blog/printing-all-prolog-answers-to-a-file

Comment: I guess the problem is rather solved by the max_depth option. See http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=write_term%2f2