# How to take out the ... from (swi) prolog output

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using SWI-Prolog Interactively - Output Taken off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252431/using-swi-prolog-interactively-output-taken-off)

I have written a program to replace X occurrences of 1 by 8 in Prolog.

The program works correct as it gives correct output. But it abbreviates my output when I give it long input. How to prevent this?

Example:

```
X = [2, 8, 3, 8, 4, 8, 5, 1, 6|...] .
```

Is the output for

```
replace_first_k(3,[2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1],X).
```

How to display all the characters of X in output terminal?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427082/prolog-showing-results-on-the-interpretator/12427222#12427222 Possible duplicate of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using

```
Write(X)
```

You can use it at each step of your function so it keeps on printing the part of array it has passed through.